# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

SharePoint's [third moderator election](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Waqas Sarwar MVP] [image: M.Qassas]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, join me in thanking [Eric Alexander](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1806/eric-alexander) and [Robert Lindgren](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15141/robert-lindgren) for their years of service as they will be stepping down.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5381059088744448/0).

Comment: congratulations guys!

Comment: Thank you everyone for voting and electing me. It is a great honor.

Comment: First of all, I am so proud to be a moderator in this great community. I would like to thank everyone for their precious confidence and for their valuable support during the election phase, I would like to thank all the candidates especially @Mike and Arsalan Adam Khatri and wish them success. They really deserve to be Moderators, I would like to thank  Eric Alexander and Robert Lindgren for their years of service, I really appreciate their valuable effort, I learned a lot from them :) and I wish them success :) . Finally, I would like to thank Jon Ericson for introducing us as Moderators :)

Comment: Congratulations guys!

Comment: Congratulations guys, well deserved. Eric Alexander and Robert Lindgren thanks for your services.

Comment: Waqas you won by a landslide

Comment: @Mike, It is surprising for me. I cant believe that people appreciate my contributions. I am thankful to everybody for their love and confidence. That's mean I have to work hard.

Comment: I would also like to say that @Mike had to be the close 3rd in this race. I have enjoyed Mike's comments and contributions over the years and he always brings a fresh perspective to any conversation! Next election you have my vote again, Mike! also, congrats to Waqas and M.Qassas! Thoroughly deserved!

Comment: Darn, I registered 1000 fake accounts to get Mike in... and I am not even Russian.. Ah well.. elections

Comment: wow, I appreciate the warm words Danny and Ransher. Just know I'm not going anywhere, I'll still be around here--just not with a sheriff's badge on.

Comment: @Danny hard Luck...May be your Fake accounts just vote for me and give you Fake news. :)

Answer (score 10):

Congratulation, new moderators!

You’ve both proven a great effort in making our community the best place online finding answers on SharePoint and Office 365 questions. It’s a great honor to have you as part of the fellowship of moderators and I’ll hope you both find your new assignment encouraging. When you have received you moderator diamond, I’ll make sure you’ll get a great start, and will invite you to our inner circle both here and in OneDrive.

If you have any question, I’ll make my best to answer as this is what we do here. :)

Comment: Thanks, @Benny for your usual support :)

Comment: Thanks @Benny, Your support and guidance.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulation for new moderators, especially I want to thank @M.Qassas who is an awesome guy and who is willing to help you at anytime.

Comment: Thank you @Nderon Hyseni

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Nderon Hyseni

Answer (score 8):

I hope I am not too late to congratulate you guys for your achievements :-P :-P.

Congratulations [@M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) and [@Waqas Sarwar MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mvp) for achieving this great milestone.

Here I would like to share something about you guys what I am observing since last more than 1 years.

[@Waqas Sarwar MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mvp) **Sir**:

Don't mind If I call you sir, you are legend here.

[image]

The image says everything about you.

Congratulations once again.

[@M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas):

You joined the community just one month after I joined. Initially I thought you are here just for promoting yourself and scoring the points, (**`I'm sorry if this hurts`**).

But later on when I kept observing your contribution towards the community and the quality of the answer you wrote to most of questions I realized that this man has some burning desire in his mind to help fellows and make community much better. Also the time you gave to this community is incredible.

I started reading your answers as it was very qualitative and I got my knowledge upgraded.

When I got choice to make the vote for moderator and I saw your name in the list, trust me, it took me less than 1 second to vote for you.

You truly deserve to be in the moderators panel for your great efforts.

Congratulations again.

Comment: I'm very pleased to read your kind words, you made my day :), thanks! 

I also had the honor to discuss with you some problems earlier, I really appreciate your valuable contribution to this community. Please Keep it up :)

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations to our new moderators, please continue the good work in providing solutions for our issues :)

Comment: Thank you @Karthik Jaganathan! Please don't hesitate to inform us in case you have any issue, we are honored to serve you :)

Comment: Thank you @Karthik, always here to help

Answer (score 6):

Hearty congratulations to new moderators.

Comment: thank you @thinkb4code

Comment: Thank you so much :) @ThinkB4Code

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations guys! Both are deserving candidates. Whenever I come across any question mostly would see @Waqas Sarwar  contribution .

So wish you mutual successful years ahead for you and well for the community.